# Unable to split and merge in XSLT

Tags: xslt

I have an Xml

`<input Inputxml="&ltOrder..&lt;LinePPlineNO=&quot;1@quot;Line/&gt; &gt;" >`

How do i remove some part of string using xsl .. for eg I need to remove a whole string from `&lt;` to `&gt;`  for a `PPline 1`

I need to splie the string in 3 parts remove the string from lt to gt and merge the part 1na dpart 3 of string

```
  <Test Attrib1="b" Attrib2="C" Inputxml="
      &lt;OrderLine  OrderedQty="1" PrimeLineNo="1" ShipNode="ABC" $gt;
       &lt;/OrderLine $gt;
     &lt;OrderLine OrderedQty="1" PrimeLineNo="2" ShipNode="ABC"  $gt;      
  &lt;/OrderLine $gt;" />
```

For example I may have 100 Order lines but I need to find the one with Prime line 1 and remove it .. So if I have to remeove a line I have to remove from lt; to gt;

Comment: Do you have any code, input to check?

Comment: So which part is your input string to split, the value of the `Inputxml` attribute? How exactly should the result look? And which version of XSLT  do you use/can you use? Also, as the attribute has the name `Inputxml`, is its value supposed to be escaped XML?

Comment: It's not getting any clearer.

Comment: ok .. I have many attributes in a xml and one of the attributes is a xml  as a string .. I dont know How to remove elements from a xml ( which is stored as a string ).. I tried using disable-output-escaping=yes .. which didint give me any xml ... If it was xml i would remove elemenst easily but it is a string.. I mean .. like lt; gt; quot;

Comment: @MartinHonnen yes I need to remove one element from the value of Inputxml .. I am using XSLT2.0.. Yes it has to be escaped xml &lt; &gt;; kinda xml ..

Comment: Since I was removing one part of that String .. I thought of getting One element frmom &lt; to &gt; and then replace that element string with  space .. It didint work .. tried substring before .. and after .. but it wont understand as there are many occurences of lt;

Answer (score 1):

Your example is confusing. If you have an XML input such as:

```
<input Inputxml="&lt;order&gt;&lt;Line PPlineNO=&quot;1&quot;&gt;Bingo&lt;/Line&gt;&lt;/order&gt;"/>
```

where the `Inputxml` attribute holds the escaped XML:

```
<order><Line PPlineNO="1">Bingo</Line></order>
```

you can use:

```
<xsl:template match="input">
    <result>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(@Inputxml, 'PPlineNO=&quot;1&quot;&gt;'), '&lt;/Line&gt;')" />
    </result>
</xsl:template>
```

to get:

```
<result>Bingo</result>
```

---

Note that is not a good way to parse XML (or rather what used to be XML). It would be much smarter to unescape it first, then parse it as XML. In XSLT 3.0, you can use the `parse-xml()` function for this. In XSLT 1.0/2.0, you can do:

```
<xsl:value-of select="@Inputxml" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
```

save the result to a file, and process the resulting file using another XSLT stylesheet.