# Parsing a variable containing xml string in xslt

Tags: html, xml, xml-parsing, xslt-2.0, saxon

I am trying to form an html template with xslt where I need to parse values from a variable containing xml string. But not being able to do so. If I try to print the variable it's showing the whole xml string with `<` and `>` being replaced with `&lt;` and `&gt;` respectively , but is not being parsed with xpath when tried.

Below is my xml string looks like which I stored in a variable named "SpecificOrderDetails". If I try the expression

`<xsl:value-of select="$SpecificOrderDetails/SPECIFICORDERDETAILS/text()"/>`

it gives me null value as output

```
<SPECIFICORDERDETAILS><ORDERROW><CATEGORY>1</CATEGORY><ACTION>0</ACTION><COMPONENTNAME>Hard-wired Return Path</COMPONENTNAME><COMPONENTID>101401</COMPONENTID></ORDERROW><ORDERROW><CATEGORY>1</CATEGORY><ACTION>0</ACTION><COMPONENTNAME>Platinum Included FBO Movies</COMPONENTNAME><COMPONENTID>101500</COMPONENTID></ORDERROW><ORDERROW><CATEGORY>1</CATEGORY><ACTION>0</ACTION><COMPONENTNAME>iQ Discount</COMPONENTNAME><COMPONENTID>101501</COMPONENTID></ORDERROW><ORDERROW><CATEGORY>1</CATEGORY><ACTION>0</ACTION><COMPONENTNAME>Primary Discounts</COMPONENTNAME><COMPONENTID>101504</COMPONENTID></ORDERROW><ORDERROW><CATEGORY>1</CATEGORY><ACTION>0</ACTION><COMPONENTNAME>03 Foxtel iQ</COMPONENTNAME><COMPONENTID>101601</COMPONENTID></ORDERROW><ORDERROW><CATEGORY>1</CATEGORY><ACTION>0</ACTION><COMPONENTNAME>TV - 24 Month Contract</COMPONENTNAME><COMPONENTID>101714</COMPONENTID></ORDERROW><ORDERROW><CATEGORY>1</CATEGORY><ACTION>0</ACTION><COMPONENTNAME>Standard Install - No Offer</COMPONENTNAME><COMPONENTID>101723</COMPONENTID></ORDERROW><ORDERROW><CATEGORY>1</CATEGORY><ACTION>0</ACTION><COMPONENTNAME>My Platinum Eligibility</COMPONENTNAME><COMPONENTID>101900</COMPONENTID></ORDERROW><ORDERROW><CATEGORY>1</CATEGORY><ACTION>0</ACTION><COMPONENTNAME>Commitment Eligibility</COMPONENTNAME><COMPONENTID>101913</COMPONENTID></ORDERROW><ORDERROW><CATEGORY>1</CATEGORY><ACTION>0</ACTION><COMPONENTNAME>Platinum Channels</COMPONENTNAME><COMPONENTID>990015</COMPONENTID></ORDERROW><ORDERROW><CATEGORY>4</CATEGORY><ACTION>0</ACTION><COMPONENTNAME>Smartcard</COMPONENTNAME><COMPONENTID>101</COMPONENTID></ORDERROW><ORDERROW><CATEGORY>4</CATEGORY><ACTION>0</ACTION><COMPONENTNAME>iQ PDR - Satellite</COMPONENTNAME><COMPONENTID>201</COMPONENTID></ORDERROW></SPECIFICORDERDETAILS>
```

If I try to print the variable it shows the whole xml string as below

```
<tr>
   <td class="headingSubText" style="font-size:13pt; padding:10px 0px 0px 15px">&lt;SPECIFICORDERDETAILS&gt;&lt;ORDERROW&gt;&lt;CATEGORY&gt;1&lt;/CATEGORY&gt;&lt;ACTION&gt;0&lt;/ACTION&gt;&lt;COMPONENTNAME&gt;Hard-wired Return Path&lt;/COMPONENTNAME&gt;&lt;COMPONENTID&gt;101401&lt;/COMPONENTID&gt;&lt;/ORDERROW&gt;&lt;ORDERROW&gt;&lt;CATEGORY&gt;1&lt;/CATEGORY&gt;&lt;ACTION&gt;0&lt;/ACTION&gt;&lt;COMPONENTNAME&gt;Platinum
      Included FBO Movies&lt;/COMPONENTNAME&gt;&lt;COMPONENTID&gt;101500&lt;/COMPONENTID&gt;&lt;/ORDERROW&gt;&lt;ORDERROW&gt;&lt;CATEGORY&gt;1&lt;/CATEGORY&gt;&lt;ACTION&gt;0&lt;/ACTION&gt;&lt;COMPONENTNAME&gt;iQ
      Discount&lt;/COMPONENTNAME&gt;&lt;COMPONENTID&gt;101501&lt;/COMPONENTID&gt;&lt;/ORDERROW&gt;&lt;ORDERROW&gt;&lt;CATEGORY&gt;1&lt;/CATEGORY&gt;&lt;ACTION&gt;0&lt;/ACTION&gt;&lt;COMPONENTNAME&gt;Primary
      Discounts&lt;/COMPONENTNAME&gt;&lt;COMPONENTID&gt;101504&lt;/COMPONENTID&gt;&lt;/ORDERROW&gt;&lt;ORDERROW&gt;&lt;CATEGORY&gt;1&lt;/CATEGORY&gt;&lt;ACTION&gt;0&lt;/ACTION&gt;&lt;COMPONENTNAME&gt;03
      Foxtel iQ&lt;/COMPONENTNAME&gt;&lt;COMPONENTID&gt;101601&lt;/COMPONENTID&gt;&lt;/ORDERROW&gt;&lt;ORDERROW&gt;&lt;CATEGORY&gt;1&lt;/CATEGORY&gt;&lt;ACTION&gt;0&lt;/ACTION&gt;&lt;COMPONENTNAME&gt;TV
      - 24 Month Contract&lt;/COMPONENTNAME&gt;&lt;COMPONENTID&gt;101714&lt;/COMPONENTID&gt;&lt;/ORDERROW&gt;&lt;ORDERROW&gt;&lt;CATEGORY&gt;1&lt;/CATEGORY&gt;&lt;ACTION&gt;0&lt;/ACTION&gt;&lt;COMPONENTNAME&gt;Standard
      Install - No Offer&lt;/COMPONENTNAME&gt;&lt;COMPONENTID&gt;101723&lt;/COMPONENTID&gt;&lt;/ORDERROW&gt;&lt;ORDERROW&gt;&lt;CATEGORY&gt;1&lt;/CATEGORY&gt;&lt;ACTION&gt;0&lt;/ACTION&gt;&lt;COMPONENTNAME&gt;My
      Platinum Eligibility&lt;/COMPONENTNAME&gt;&lt;COMPONENTID&gt;101900&lt;/COMPONENTID&gt;&lt;/ORDERROW&gt;&lt;ORDERROW&gt;&lt;CATEGORY&gt;1&lt;/CATEGORY&gt;&lt;ACTION&gt;0&lt;/ACTION&gt;&lt;COMPONENTNAME&gt;Commitment
      Eligibility&lt;/COMPONENTNAME&gt;&lt;COMPONENTID&gt;101913&lt;/COMPONENTID&gt;&lt;/ORDERROW&gt;&lt;ORDERROW&gt;&lt;CATEGORY&gt;1&lt;/CATEGORY&gt;&lt;ACTION&gt;0&lt;/ACTION&gt;&lt;COMPONENTNAME&gt;Platinum
      Channels&lt;/COMPONENTNAME&gt;&lt;COMPONENTID&gt;990015&lt;/COMPONENTID&gt;&lt;/ORDERROW&gt;&lt;ORDERROW&gt;&lt;CATEGORY&gt;4&lt;/CATEGORY&gt;&lt;ACTION&gt;0&lt;/ACTION&gt;&lt;COMPONENTNAME&gt;Smartcard&lt;/COMPONENTNAME&gt;&lt;COMPONENTID&gt;101&lt;/COMPONENTID&gt;&lt;/ORDERROW&gt;&lt;ORDERROW&gt;&lt;CATEGORY&gt;4&lt;/CATEGORY&gt;&lt;ACTION&gt;0&lt;/ACTION&gt;&lt;COMPONENTNAME&gt;iQ
      PDR - Satellite&lt;/COMPONENTNAME&gt;&lt;COMPONENTID&gt;201&lt;/COMPONENTID&gt;&lt;/ORDERROW&gt;&lt;/SPECIFICORDERDETAILS&gt;
   </td>
</tr>
```

Please help someone on how to parse the variable inside xslt . Let know if  I was not clear enough. This would my first question ever asked on stackoverflow.

Comment: Please post the xml and xslt file too - not just snippets - snough for a [mcve]

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58777137/unable-to-split-and-merge-in-xslt/58778461#58778461

Comment: If you can use XSLT 3 or at least XPath 3 then you have functions `parse-xml` and `parse-xml-fragment` you can use, see https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWEamLi.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, thanks for the example. but I have to use xslt 2.0 .

Comment: @michael.hor257k. I have used the ```disable-output-escaping="yes"```, but no luck

Comment: Check whether your XSLT 2 processor provides an extension similar to `parse-xml`. Otherwise you need to run two separate transformations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working !

Used **xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"** extension for xslt2.0 and it works perfectly to parse the xml string in the variable like below.

```
<xsl:value-of select="saxon:parse($SpecificOrderDetails)/SPECIFICORDERDETAILS/ORDERROW[ACTION ='0']"/>
```

Thanks everyone for helping!

Comment: In XSLT 3.0 this Saxon extension function became part of the W3C standard, under the name `parse-xml()`. (It doesn't make much sense to say you have to use XSLT 2.0, and then to use a vendor extension to XSLT 2.0).

Comment: I tried changing the xslt version to 3.0 and try the parse-xml() , but it failed while compiling stylesheet  with some "unknown method or function parse-xml()  ", hence tried with the extension. I am not sure which XSLT procesor is being used, but it does not support XSLT3.0 it seems

Comment: It's a good idea to know which XSLT processor you are using. You can find out by using `<xsl:message select="system-property('xsl:vendor'), system-property('xsl:product-version')"/>`